# building an donor attribution program in R

Tags: r

My non-profit is working to understand the value of different fundraising campaigns. 
I have data that looks like this:

```
donor <- data.frame(
                    donor_names=c("Donor1","Donor1","Donor2","Donor3","Donor3"),
                    donor_id=c("0A1","0A1","0A2","0A3","0A3"),
                    amount=c(500,400,300,250,100),
                    date=c("1/5/2012","11/10/2011","1/4/2012","1/14/2012","1/10/2012"),
                    campaign=c("grassroots","2012-annual appeal","grassroots","grassroots","Jan10 Auction"),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
                   )

donor$date <- as.Date(donor$date,format="%m/%d/%Y")

  donor_names donor_id amount       date           campaign
1      Donor1      0A1    500 2012-01-05         grassroots
2      Donor1      0A1    400 2011-11-10 2012-annual appeal
3      Donor2      0A2    300 2012-01-04         grassroots
4      Donor3      0A3    250 2012-01-14         grassroots
5      Donor3      0A3    100 2012-01-10      Jan10 Auction
```

I need to see how much of donations can be attributed to each campaign given that all future contributions of a donor can be attributed the campaign that they first donated to.

An end result would return "2012-annual appeal" with 900, "grassroots" with 300, and "Jan10 Auction" with 350.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aggregate by `donor_names` (summing `amount` and keeping `campaign` corresponding to the earliest `date`), then aggregate that by `campaign`.

Answer (score 4):

```
library("plyr")

ddply(ddply(donor,
            .(donor_names),
            summarize,
            amount = sum(amount),
            campaign = campaign[date == min(date)]),
      .(campaign),
      summarize,
      amount = sum(amount))
```

which gives

```
            campaign amount
1 2012-annual appeal    900
2         grassroots    300
3      Jan10 Auction    350
```